# API Gateway is not calling global mediaton extension - WSO2 AM 2.2.0

Tags: wso2, mediator, apache-synapse, api-gateway

I am following given [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) to create a global synapse mediator, but it seems that my mediator is not used. When I upload the same mediator XML to the API on publisher, works properly.

My XML meditor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <property name="X-Client-Remote-Addr" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REMOTE_ADDR')" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="X-Client-Forwarded-For" expression="$trp:X-Forwarded-For" scope="transport"/>
</sequence>
```

The API handlers sequence is the default, using *org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler* like this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Writing+Custom+Handlers). This handler should be the responsible to apply global mediators.

Is there some known bug with a workaround or, maybe, did I some mistake?

Comment: It should work if the file is deployed properly. Did you observe any errors in the log while it's being deployed?

Comment: Yes. The application log shows given message:INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : WSO2AM--Ext--In was added to the Synapse configuration successfully

Comment: Another detail that I could observe is that the logs from APIManagerExtensionHandler are not logged. I think that there is some throuble in synapse handlers.

Comment: The "yes" on the last comment was about the log, but I did not abserve any error.

Comment: If your API published? If is in prototype mode, check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624765/wso2-apim-custom-sequences-for-non-published-apis-setting-variable/50656421#50656421

Comment: Yes, my api is published, and the API XML generated using the template that you mentioned in your question contains the entry with APIManagerExtensionHandler. Do you have another idea?